# Trying to store json data into an javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following json data that looks like this...

[image]

What I am trying to do is store the temp numbers into a javascript array to display on a graph. This is my code that I was working on...

```html
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Redlands,us&mode=json&units=imperial&cnt=20&APPID=5eea63b2ee3505c58713d9149832d4c5",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                //console.log(data.list[0].main.temp);
                //trying to parse through data for graph
                var date = [];
                $.each(data,function(index, data){
                    date.append(data.list[index].main.temp);
                });

            }


        });
```

But it is not working I get the following error...
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: `city`? what? that's not even in the code you gave us so the error couldn't be here.

Comment: Each over data.list and not only data.

Comment: The part of the code is where I am getting the error. Specifically the date.append(data.list[index].main.temp part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see working  , same from Erik Engervall, i change var data for current

```
    $.each(data.list,function(index, current){
                date.push(current.main.temp);
     });
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. I also figured it out using just plain javascript after the fact. But thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're iterating over the entire data object, whereas I believe you only wish to iterate over the data.list:

```
$.each(data.list, function(index, val) {
    date.push(val.main.temp);
});
```

Also, JavaScript arrays uses [`push`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp).

Updated answer after Mikel.

Comment: I still get the same error weatherapp.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. Maybe I am accessing the json data the wrong way?

Comment: Is line 49 in your code "date.push(data.list[index].main.temp);"?

Answer (score -3):

You need to use JSON.parse().

```
var dataList = JSON.parse(data).list;
```

Comment: No, this would make things worse.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't see that dataType has been set. My bad. There's no attempt to access a property 'city' there anyway.